# DataGridView in Windows form using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

Here I need to create one gridview and add values from the text file . Text files contains list of email ids. After displaying those email ids in row by row , i need to fetch those one by one and split it by "@" character . In next columns i need to show those split values. Like as follows

```
Email             username   domain

abcd@gmail.com     abcd      gmail
catdog@gmail.com   catdog    gmail
```

Comment: You could hire somebody, we won't write code for you.

Comment: did you try something or it is just a do-my-homework question?

Comment: Next time when you ask question, please provide code which you already have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create class `Email`:

```
public class Email
{
    public Email(string email)
    {
        Address = email;
        int index = email.IndexOf('@');
        UserName = email.Substring(0, index);
        Domain = email.Substring(index + 1);
    }

    public string Address { get; private set; }    
    public string UserName { get; private set; }    
    public string Domain { get; private set; }
}
```

And data-bind your grid to instances of this class:

```
var emails = from line in File.ReadLines(fileName)
             select new Email(line);

grid.DataSource = emails.ToList();
```

If you need first column to be named `Email`, then add columns manually and provide names of email class properties as `DataPropertyName` for each column.

**UPDATE:** There is already existing class [`MailAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress.aspx) in *System.Net.Mail* namespace which you can use for same purpose:

```
var emails = from line in File.ReadLines(fileName)
             select new MailAddress(line);
```

It has properties `Address`, `User` and `Host` which serve your needs.

Comment: thanks a lot @lazybereZovsky... sorry i forget to post my coding